# Is Apple's Core Image framework open source?

Tags: open-source

Is the source of Apple's [Core Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Image) framework open as [other open source projects](https://www.apple.com/opensource/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope it is not.

Only a few components in OSX are open source (Kernel, BSD inherited components, Grand Central Dispatch). Non of the Core Frameworks (Image, Storage, Animation, Graphics) are open source.

Comment: All open source components are listed on the page the OP links to

Comment: Then why isn't lidispatch there ?

Comment: What is lidispatch and if not there then a bug and should be reported to Apple

Comment: It's for GCD. But it seems to be that Apache is behind it, not Apple : http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/

Comment: Is it part of OSX or just can be used? The list is of any open source OSX uses not what Apple has contributed to

Comment: Well it seems it's used by OSX : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch

Comment: The more exact page is http://opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-1094/ I am now confused as to what the OP points to

Comment: It seems to be they are only Open Source components not coming from Apple itself.